# Detecting _vars_with_underscores_; why does this not work?

Tags: javascript, parsing, grammar, pegjs

I am trying to write a PEGjs rule to convert

```
Return _a_b_c_.
```

to

```
Return <>a_b_c</>.
```

My grammar is

```
root = atoms:atom+
{ return atoms.join(''); }

atom = variable
     / normalText

variable = "_" first:variableSegment rest:$("_" variableSegment)* "_"
{ return '<>' + first + rest + '</>'; }

variableSegment = $[^\n_ ]+

normalText = $[^\n]
```

This works for

```
Return _a_b_c_ .
```

and

```
Return _a_b_c_
```

but something is going wrong with the

```
Return _a_b_c_.
```

example.

I can't quite understand why this is breaking, and would love an explanation of why it's behaving as it does. (I don't even need a solution to the problem, necessarily; the biggest issue is that my mental model of PEGjs grammars is deficient.)

Comment: `_.` matches the `"_" variableSegment` part, but then the trailing `"_"` is missing, that's why the `normalText` rule is used. (`Return _a_b_c_.`  is _the same_ as `Return _a_b_c_d`)

Comment: Why doesn't it see that the rule isn't going to match when interpreted that way, and instead interpret the last _ as the trailing _?

Comment: When it fails upon seeing no trailing `_` after the `.`, it backtracks by assuming that the *leading* `_a` are "normal". I'm not sure I know why.

Comment: Oh - let me edit my answer again if you don't want that trailing `_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearranging the grammar slightly makes it work:

```
root = atoms:atom+
{ return atoms.join(''); }

atom = variable
     / normalText

variable = "_" first:$(variableSegment "_") rest:$(variableSegment "_")*
{ return '<>' + first + rest + '</>'; }

variableSegment = seg:$[^\n_ ]+

normalText = normal:$[^\n]
```

I'm not sure I understand why, exactly. In this one, the parser gets to the "." and matches it as a "variableSegment", but then backtracks just one step in the greedy "*" lookahead, decides it's got a "variable", and then re-parses the "." as "normal". (Note that this picks up the trailing `_`, which if not desired can be snipped off by a hack in action, or something like that; see below.)

In the original version, after failing because of the missing trailing underscore, the very next step the parser takes is back to the *leading* underscore, opting for the "normal" interpretation.

I added some action code with `console.log()` calls to trace the parser behavior.

*edit* — I think the deal is this. In your original version, the parse is failing on a rule that's of the form

> expr1 expr2 expr3 ... exprN

The first sub-expression is the literal `_`. The next is for the first variable segment. The third is for the sequence of variable expressions preceded by `_`, and the last is the trailing `_`.  While working through that rule on the problematic input, the last expression fails.  The others have all *succeeded*, however, so the only place to start over is at the alternative point in the "atom" rule.

In the revised version, the parser can unwind the operation of the greedy `*` by one step. It then has a successful match of the third expression, so the rule succeeds.

Thus another revision, closer to the original, will also work:

```
root = atoms:atom+
{ return atoms.join(''); }

atom = variable
     / normalText

variable = "_" first:variableSegment rest:$("_" variableSegment & "_")* "_"
{ return '<>' + first + rest + '</>'; }

variableSegment = $[^\n_ ]+

normalText = $[^\n]
```

Now that greedy `*` group will backtrack when it fails in peeking forward at an `_`.

Comment: That's because the rule is not _ambiguous_  anymore. Eiter it will find another `variableSegment "_"`  or the variable is finished (it is the last part in that rule). PEG.js does not go a step backwards inside of the `variable`. It tries to match it step by step, either with a fulfillment (in your case) or a failure in the original code. (Sorry for the bad explanation)

Comment: @t.niese yes that's what I meant in the portion I just edited in. Once one of the subexpressions matches, it won't backtrack within the list. I don't have a deep understanding of *why* but I assume it's just the semantics of the meta-grammar.

Comment: I think it is defined that way for PEG.js to avoid situation where it isn't possible anymore to determine why a certain portion of the text will match the grammar. The more  flexible parser is the hard it will be to debug the rules.

Comment: @t.niese yes, it makes sense for it to be reluctant to backtrack that aggressively since it's possible to be more explicit in the grammar anyway.

Comment: This is super-helpful.

I made a mistake in my original; the output should be `Return <>a_b_c</>` (no trailing `_`). I edited my OP, and you might want to edit your answer so as to not confuse future people, but your dissection of the problem helps immensely.

Comment: In particular the `&"_") "_"` trick is great to have in my repertoire.

Comment: I love questions about PEG.js because I have no need for it in my day-to-day life :)

Answer (score 0):

The parser interprets the last `_.` as variableSegment. If you exclude the the dot from the `variableSegment` RegExp your code will work as expected.

Comment: I don't think that the "." character has any particular significance.

Comment: please add some more details

Comment: variableSegment = $[^\n_\. ]+

As fgnass said, excluding the . fixes the problem. Have you tried using http://pegjs.majda.cz/online?

Comment: Yes but then `Return _a_b_c_d` would still not work as intended.

Comment: As I understand @Domenic's grammar vars should always end with an underscore?

Comment: @fgnass yes, but the problem is that he wants it to see the complete "variable" that's there before the trailing character, whatever it is,